# Change "Add to bag" to "Add to cart"

Tags: 6, theming, ubercart

In the following [website](http://www.tijostyle.com/tops/rose-sheer-blouse.html), I want to change the string from "Add to bag" to "Add to cart." I am using Drupal 6 and Ubercart.

How could I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this in Ubercart settings using no extra modules...

Go to `/admin/store/settings/products/edit/general`, which is in **Store administration -> Configuration -> Product settings -> Edit -> Product settings** in the menu.

The text for 'Add to cart' is editable in the `Add to cart button text` section.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module for tweaking the label from any Drupal module or theme.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module, and point and click on the text. You'll get the theming method or template you have to overwrite/create to tweak the UI to your needs.